# iTunes Store Customer Reviews API XML Endpoint Broken

Tags: json, xml, itunes-store

I used to use the XML endpoint because it provided review dates for each review called 'updated'. This is not contained in the JSON endpoint. However, the XML endpoint stopped working. I get the error seen below:

```
Web Server Error
Description: The host did not return the document correctly.
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Any workarounds? Do you anticipate this will ever be fixed by Apple? Do you think the JSON endpoint might be taken down any time soon?

**XML Endpoint (Broken)**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/mostrecent/xml

**JSON Endpoint (Working)**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/mostrecent/json

Comment: Experienced the same issue, couldn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the XML endpoint is up and running again. No more Web Server Error. Hopefully the endpoint stays up.